# setdropdownviewresource identifier expected

Tags: android, spinner

Trying to make a spinner in android:

```
package com.example.test; 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

public class SpinnerBuilding extends Activity {
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.building);

// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.buildings_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

It throws an error saying `"Syntax error on token "setDropDownViewResource", identifier expected after this token.` Moreover, the `spinner.setAdapter(adapter);` also does not work.

Could somebody help me with this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the whole code inside some method, You cannot execute code from outside of method in a class.

Preferably move the whole code inside Oncreate.

```
public class SpinnerBuilding extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle b){

super.onCreate(b);
setContentView(R.id.layout);
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.building);

// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.buildings_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Comment: Right... I forgot... great... Thank you verymuch!! So fixated to my other code that I forgot this...

Comment: Can't seem to get it works... There is no syntax error now. However, the spinner does not show at all. I wonder why..?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this just somewhere in your class. I recommend putting pretty much everything you have into onCreate() method

Answer (score 0):

You should set adapter inside Oncreate(). And also use setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout).